# Compare Javascript array object and return closest pair

Tags: javascript

**Array 1**

```
[{
  "index": 3,
  "ratio": 1.9310344827586208
}, {
  "index": 0,
  "ratio": 2.4122497055359244
}, {
  "index": 2,
  "ratio": 2.5
}, {
  "index": 1,
  "ratio": 1
}]
```

**Array 2**

```
[{
"index": 0,
  "ratio": 0.6670000000000006
}, {
  "index": 2,
  "ratio": 1
}, {
  "index": 3,
  "ratio": 1
}, {
  "index": 1,
  "ratio": 2.409638554216892
}]
```

I want result like

From Array 1 ratio "2.4122497055359244" and Array 2 ration"2.409638554216892" is closest pair

```
[{array1: 0, array2:1}, {array1: 1, array2:2}, ....]
```

Comment: I'd say this is a good candidate for javascripts .map()

Comment: Why have you tagged it with [php]?

Comment: Why have you tagged it with [html]? Please stop adding non-relevant tags to get attention.

Comment: @ThomasDeutschländer it's all about logic not technical language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function findNearestRatio(item,array){
    var val = array.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
      var difference = Math.abs(curr.ratio-item.ratio);
      return difference<acc.diff?{diff:difference,item:curr}:acc;
    },{diff:1000});
    return val;
}

var sortFunc = (a,b) => {
  if(a.difference<b.difference){
    return -1;
  }else if(a.difference>b.difference){
    return 1;
  }else{
    return 0;
  }
};

var array1 = [{ index: 3, ratio: 1.9310344827586208 }, { index: 0, ratio: 2.4122497055359244 }, { index: 2, ratio: 2.5 }, { index: 1, ratio: 1 }],
array2 = [{ index: 0, ratio: 0.6670000000000006 }, { index: 2, ratio: 1 }, { index: 3, ratio: 1 }, { index: 1, ratio: 2.409638554216892 }];
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array1)), JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array2)));
var bestIndexArray = [];
while(array1.length) {
  var closest = findNearestRatio(array1[0], array2);
  closest.org = array1[0];
  for (var j = 1; j < array1.length; j++) {
    var closest2 = findNearestRatio(array1[j], array2);
    if(closest2.item.index === closest.item.index && closest.diff > closest2.diff) {
      closest2.org = array1[j];
      closest = closest2;
    }
  }                  
  bestIndexArray.push({array1: closest.org.index, array2:closest.item.index});
  array1.splice(array1.indexOf(closest.org), 1);
  array2.splice(array2.indexOf(closest.item), 1);
}
console.log(bestIndexArray);
```

**OUTPUT**
[image: OUTPUT]

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the first array and take from the second array the smallest deltas. If more than one item is the smallest, both items are included in the result set.

The result is sorted by the closest items.

```js
function delta(a, b) {
    return Math.abs(a - b);
}

var array1 = [{ index: 3, ratio: 1.9310344827586208 }, { index: 0, ratio: 2.4122497055359244 }, { index: 2, ratio: 2.5 }, { index: 1, ratio: 1 }],
    array2 = [{ index: 0, ratio: 0.6670000000000006 }, { index: 2, ratio: 1 }, { index: 3, ratio: 1 }, { index: 1, ratio: 2.409638554216892 }],
    result = array1
        .reduce((r, a) => r.concat(array2.reduce((s, b) => {
            var d1 = s && delta(a.ratio, b.ratio),
                d2 = s && delta(a.ratio, s[0].b.ratio);

            if (!s || d1 < d2) {
                return [{ delta: delta(a.ratio, b.ratio), a, b }];
            }
            if (d1 === d2) {
                s.push({ delta: delta(a.ratio, b.ratio), a, b });
            }
            return s;
        }, undefined)), [])
        .sort((a, b) => a.delta - b.delta)
        .map(({ a: { index: array1 }, b: { index: array2 } }) => ({ array1, array2 }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Just take the first smallest delta.

```js
function delta(a, b) {
    return Math.abs(a - b);
}

var array1 = [{ index: 3, ratio: 1.9310344827586208 }, { index: 0, ratio: 2.4122497055359244 }, { index: 2, ratio: 2.5 }, { index: 1, ratio: 1 }],
    array2 = [{ index: 0, ratio: 0.6670000000000006 }, { index: 2, ratio: 1 }, { index: 3, ratio: 1 }, { index: 1, ratio: 2.409638554216892 }],
    result = array1
        .reduce((r, a) => r.concat(array2.reduce((s, b) => {
            var d1 = s && delta(a.ratio, b.ratio),
                d2 = s && delta(a.ratio, s[0].b.ratio);

            return !s || d1 < d2
                ? [{ delta: delta(a.ratio, b.ratio), a, b }]
                : s;
        }, undefined)), [])
        .sort((a, b) => a.delta - b.delta)
        .map(({ a: { index: array1 }, b: { index: array2 } }) => ({ array1, array2 }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: it return duplicate value

Comment: what is a duplicate? do you need just one with the same delta?

Comment: it return duplicate index of array2 (index should be unique), check my below answer for output